# Printing a function in Python

Tags: python

I'm just starting to learn Python, and I'm currently reading a book that is teaching me,
and in the book a function just like the one I have made below prints the actual text that is defined in the first function, but when I run my script it says: 
`<function two at 0x0000000002E54EA0>` as the output. What am I doing wrong? Did I install the wrong Python or something? I downloaded the 3.3.0 version

Here is my code:

```
def one():
    print ("lol")
    print ("dood")

def two():
    print (one)
    print (one)

print (two)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your functions already print text, you don't need to print the functions. Just call them (don't forget parenthesis).

```
def one():
    print ("lol")
    print ("dood")

def two():
    one()
    one()

two()
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this book is a little different than Python is now, its the How To Think Python book from greenteapress.com

Answer (score 23):

This is not the answer you are looking for…

But in interest of completeness, suppose you did want to print the code of the function itself. This will only work if the code was executed from a file (not a REPL).

```
import inspect
code, line_no = inspect.getsourcelines(two)
print(''.join(code))
```

That said, there aren't many good reasons for doing this.

Comment: Not the right question but the right heading and the right answer.

Comment: Thank you! I came here based on the questions title and you nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

You call a function in the following syntax

```
def two():
    one()
    one()

two()
```

What goes inside the parenthesis is the input parameters which you would learn later in the book.

Comment: worth noting that this will print also `None`?

Comment: I just did that and it says invalid syntax?

Comment: I think I made a mistake. I put print one() inside the definition of def two(). I corrected it now.

Answer (score 1):

The printing happens inside your function. The function itself is a sequence of code to be executed. In your case, this code is printing `"lol"` and `"dood"` to the screen. In order to execute this code, you *call* the function simply by typing its name:

```
def one():
   print("lol")
   print("dood")

def two():
   one() #simply type the function's name to execute its code
   one()

two()
```

Calling `print` on the function itself prints a the location in memory of the code that the function executes when it is called, hence your garbled output.

Answer (score -1):

you are printing the function itself, not what the function should print, maybe you wanted to print this way

```
def one():
    print ("lol")
    print ("dood")

def two():
    print one()
    print one()

print two()
```

the output would be:
lol
dood

Comment: I figured it out, it wouldn't let me use print one(), just one() to call the function

Comment: This will also print `None` 3 times.

Comment: In function two(), your just printing the one() function twice, not "lol" "dude" "lol" "dude"