# Python - Grade Calculator

Tags: python

New to StackOverflow so pardon my typos. I just started out with learning Python recently, thus as I was practicing on with writing some codes, I have come across these very unusual bug in my script which shouldn't be there. Please help me understand why and and how to get rid of it. I tried making a **Grade Calculator** and here's the script that I have written:

```
def ComputeGrade(Score):
    if score < 0 or score > 1:
        print ("Bad Score")
    elif score == 10.0:
        print ("Bad Score")
    elif score < 10.0:
        print ("A")
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print ("B")
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print ("C")
    elif score >= 0.6:
        print ("D")
    elif score < 0.6:
        print ("F")

try:
   score = float(input("Enter Score: "))
   print (ComputeGrade(score))
except ValueError as e:
    print ("Bad Score")
```

`Instead of giving me a output as a "Grade" or an error message "Bad Score" **ONLY** it shows the **None** value as well
It would really nice of you if you could explain it to me what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, just like other posts said, you have `print` twice.  Also, your logic doesn't look right and here is something for your reference:

```
def ComputeGrade(score):

    if score > 0 and score <= 1:
        if score < 0.6:
            print("F")
        elif score < 0.7:
            print("D")
        elif score < 0.8:
            print("C")
        elif score < 0.9:
            print("B")
        else:
            print("A")
    else:
        print("Bad Score")

try:
   score = float(input("Enter Score: "))
   ComputeGrade(score)
except ValueError as e:
    print ("Bad Score")
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm still learning, I just started out like a month ago, so my logic is still very newbish. Thanks to all those amazing comments over here I guess I can learn really quick now!
And got to say, your script looks really clean and organized I guess I should use yours as a reference from now on.

Answer (score 3):

Your parameter is Score with a capital 'S' and you are using the variable score with a lower case 's'. Make sure they match or it will consider them different variables. Score != score

also if you want print(ComputeGrade(score)) to print a value it needs to have a value returned in the ComputeGrade() function. i.e.

```
def printvalue():
    return "VALUE"
print(printvalue()) #this prints out the returned value of printvalue()
```

Comment: Your second suggestion is not necessary. In Python you do not need to split the bounds up as you have stated.

Comment: Oh cool I didn't know that. Thanks for the info I edited my answer.

Comment: Yup. Another small reason why Python is awesome.

Comment: Score != score was literally the first thing that I learned in Python! How could I forget that so soon, so dumb of me. Anyway thanks for the help! It helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have said, you don't need to `print` a second time. Just call the function:

```
ComputeGrade(score)
```

By the way, there is a problem with your grade calculator as shown here because all valid grades will turn out to be an "A", since all valid grades hit the first `elif` statement and are less than 10 (shouldn't this be 1.0 and not 10?). Additionally, you do not have any cut-off point between A and B (I assume it should be 0.9?).

Suggestion: anytime you find yourself using a lot of `elif` statements, consider using a dictionary instead. A dictionary allows you to "look up" something based on a value.

It might look like this (since variables are case sensitive I have switched `score` to lowercase):

```
def ComputeGrade(score):
    grade_lookup = {
                    0<=score: "F",
                    0.6<=score: "D",
                    0.7<=score: "C",
                    0.8<=score: "B",
                    0.9<=score<=1.0: "A",
                    }

    grade = grade_lookup.get(True, "Bad Score")
    print(grade)

while True:
    try:
        score = float(input("Enter Score: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Bad number entered; try again.")

ComputeGrade(score)
```

The `grade_lookup` dictionary evaluates each greater-than statement and adds it to the dictionary. If the greater-than statement is true, it adds `True` as a key, and `False` if it is false. Since a dictionary can only have a single `True` key at a time, each time the greater-than statement turns out to be true, the grade is updated (from F to A).

Then the dictionary `get` method looks up the grade associated with `True`. If there isn't one, that means the score that was given is not between 0 and 1.0, and isn't a valid score. In this case, the `get` method returns `'Bad Score'`.

Comment: I like your neat answer. Learn something new today.  But notice that you may need to convert `score` to `float` data type such as `score = float(input("Enter Score: "))`

Comment: @ian0411 yeah i had deleted that intending to do it somewhere else, changed my mind and forgot to put it back. thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but what you have said there now goes way over my head now since I just started out like a month ago. I haven't touched topics like tuples and dictionaries yet, so there's still a lot to learn for me.
But honestly, I did learn something new and it did help even if it overboard for now.

Comment: @Jarmos great. also: I understand if it seems over your head or overwhelming, but tuples and dictionaries are CRITICAL (and very basic) parts of the language so please learn them as soon as possible before you continue with much more coding.

Comment: @Jarmos in many ways the python dictionary might be the most imporant part of the language. nothing in the language is probably more important.

Comment: @RickTeachey Yeah I thought so, honestly I have enrolled myself on Coursera and downloaded a couple of books, the one that I'm reading at the moment. I'm half way through it and it teaches about tuples and dictionaries right after a couple more chapters. So I'm sure I'll be reading more of it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stake Overflow!

The line:

```
print (ComputeGrade(score))
```

Actually prints the function's location in memory, not what is in the function. Since you already are printing inside ComputeGrade, there is no need to print.

You could either:

Have ComputeGrade return a string, and print that

```
def ComputeGrade(score):
...
elif (score >= 0.8):
    return "B"
...

print ComputeGrade(score)
```

Or you could continue to print in the function itself and remove the print statement on ComputeGrade:

```
ComputeGrade(score)
```

Here's [a similar question to yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330016/printing-a-function-in-python)

Comment: It makes so much sense now, thanks for the suggestions. I'm still learning and have started out with it like a month ago. Any suggestions are a huge confidence boost for me.